# Find attribute and element from var with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have innerHTML in variable which is get as follows:

```
 var mash = e.currentTarget.innerHTML;
```

and Now mash has following values:

```
"<div class="mashup-details-view">    <div class="mashup-item" data-mashup-id="36967" id="mashup-sort-id">         <div class="mashup-thumbnail" title="Cist">          <span class="x-small thumbnail" style="min-width: 60px; min-height: 34px;"><img onerror="javascript:vidizmo.app.utils.handle_thumbnail_error(this);" src="http://az2213.vo.msecnd.net/vidizmodev/001419/081358/Images/00000c/ImgThumbs/Copa_67100313-4f60-46ff-95c1-907c75b077a8_th1.jpg"></span> </div> <div class="IconDescDiv">     <div class="TitleClass" href="#" title="Cist">Cist</div> </div> </div></div> "
```

Now i need to get "data-mashup-id" attribute , img tag and class="TitleClass" element how can i get them from variable i am trying to get it via find('img') but cant get it.
Please any body can figure this out???

Comment: do you really need to create the mash variable?  its value is not a valid string as you listed.  just use .prop to get the attributes you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `innerHTML` for this. `innerHTML` generates a string representation of the elements. You want to work directly with the elements.

First, get a jQuery wrapper around the current target:

```
// `mash` is a jQuery wrapper around the current target
var mash = $(e.currentTarget);
```

Now you can use CSS selectors to find content within the target and retrieve information from it.

Getting the `data-mashup-id` value:

```
// `id` is a string
var id = mash.find("[data-mashup-id"]).attr("data-mashup-id");
```

Getting the image (you can get information about the image from the resulting object):

```
// `img` is a jQuery wrapper around the `img` element
var img = mash.find("img");
```

Getting the `div` with the "TitleClass":

```
// `titleElement` is a jQuery wrapper around the `div` with the class
// "TitleClass"
var titleElement = mash.find("div.TitleClass");
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you use `.attr` instead of `.data`?

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: Just that there's no reason to use `data` to retrieve an attribute value, and `data` is easily misunderstood. So unless the OP is using it, I don't introduce it. People tend to assume it's shorthand for interacting with `data-*` attributes, and of course, it *isn't*, and I've seen that confuse people. Here's an example of the kind of thing I've seen confuse people (with more commentary): http://jsbin.com/ubodih/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/ubodih/1/edit)). (Thanks for the edit, btw!)

Comment: I agree that it's easily misunderstood and also misused in many cases, but in this case the OP probably want the ID as an `int` (as long as it's not a 64bit int) in which case `.data` would have done the type conversion automatically. I try to use `.data` where it makes sense, such as this case. I think it's better to teach people how to use `.data` properly instead of just going with `.attr`.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall: I disagree that `data`'s implicit type conversion is a good thing. :-) (And thanks, btw, I didn't know that.) I have no problem with teaching how to use `data` correctly, but when it's completely unrelated to the task at hand, it's just getting in the way of a clear explanation of the task at hand. When teaching, it's best to avoid introducing extraneous off-point topics.